# How do I update a control from a static method using beginInvoke?

Tags: wpf, xaml, begininvoke

I seem to be caught in a Catch 22. I am using BeginInvoke to update a control on my xaml form. However the beginInvoke requires a static method and a static method cannot update a xaml control.

```
public delegate void UpdateTextCallback(string message);
```

Here is my BeginInvoke:

```
public static void runProcess2()
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\lcsrel\prerelease\lcs\6.0\se_w16_ship\Latest\en-US\amd64fre\Test\Tools\RunUCTest.cmd";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/RunTestsVM /tests:+suite=null  /Topology:eepool_ap_onprem /LeaveVmsRunning /VMCopyBuild:Minimal ";

    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var localSender = sender;
        // Prepend line numbers to each line of the output.
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            try
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new UpdateTextCallback(UpdateText), "\n" + e.Data);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.Message;
            }

        };
    };

process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

process.Start();

// Asynchronously read the standard output of the spawned process. 
// This raises OutputDataReceived events for each line of output.
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () =>
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Close();

        });
}
```

Here is the update method:

```
private static void UpdateText(string message)
{        
   rt_output.AppendText(message);
}
```

But here I get:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property Windows4.rt_output.

`rt_output` is the control.

If I remove the static keyword from this method then I get an error in BeginInvoke:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property Windows4.UpdateText(string).

Comment: Can you update your post with the whole method that the line `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new UpdateTextCallback(UpdateText), "\n[" + lineCount++ + "]: " + e.Data);` is in? Do you have access to `rt_output` when you do the `BeginInvoke`?

Comment: You need an instance of the window class to send the updates to, I can't see how you're accessing `UpdateText` or where that method lives, how are you accessing your window?

Comment: UpdateText is called in the BeginInvoke call.

Comment: Adding a comment to get attention. Is there anything more you need to help me with this?